# How to add multiple UIImageView in a TableView Cell programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to add 3 labels & 3 images in a single Tableview cell.
 here's my labels & image views

```
let Namelbl:UILabel={
        let label=UILabel()
        label.text="item"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label

    }()
    let Namelbl2:UILabel={
        let label2=UILabel()
        label2.text="item"
        label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label2

    }()
    let Namelbl3:UILabel={
        let label3=UILabel()
        label3.text="item"
        label3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label3

    }()
    let image1: UIImageView = {
        let theImageView1 = UIImageView()
        theImageView1.image = UIImage(named: "Masjid")
        theImageView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return theImageView1
    }()
    let image2: UIImageView = {
        let theImageView2 = UIImageView()
        theImageView2.image = UIImage(named: "Masjid2")
        theImageView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return theImageView2
    }()
    let image3: UIImageView = {
        let theImageView3 = UIImageView()
        theImageView3.image = UIImage(named: "Masjid3")
        theImageView3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return theImageView3
    }()
```

And here's my function for setting up view with constraints

```
func setupViews(){
    addSubview(Namelbl)
    addSubview(Namelbl2)
    addSubview(Namelbl3)
    addSubview(image1)
    addSubview(image2)
    addSubview(image3)
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-16-[v0]-16-[v1]-16-[v2]-16-[v3]-16-[v4]-16-[v5]-50-|",options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": Namelbl,"v1":Namelbl2,"v2":Namelbl3,"v3":image1,"v4":image2,"v5":image3]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": Namelbl]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": Namelbl2]))
         addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": Namelbl3]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": image1]))

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": image2]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": image3]))


    }
```

the problem is this works just fine for 3 labels & one image it doesn't show the other two images

Comment: What's the *exact* issue? "Not showing" those other two images are a bit vague. For instance, have you set a breakpoint and determined that `image2` and `image3` are not nil? Are you receiving any console feedback?

Comment: Yes I have done that image2 & image3 are not nil.

Comment: And what's the width of theses elements? Doesn't seem to be set.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against adding views to your cells in code(*). I suggest setting up your table view to use custom cell templates. You can then define custom one or more subclasses of UITableViewCell with outlets that link to your image views, and when you dequeue a cell with your specific identifier you'll get a cell of the correct class with outlets linked and ready to set up. All you have to do is cast it to the correct type and then configure it's views.

(*) Adding views to cells in code is more work, and it also requires special handling. If you're not careful then every time you dequeue a cell you add another set of views. When you fix that you need some mechanism to access the views you added when the cell was initially created, and a typical approach like using `viewWithTag(_:)` is fragile.

Comment: Actually I am putting everything programmatically without anything to do with storyboard:)

Comment: That's ill-advised.

Comment: you are right but that's my assignment to do it this way:(

Comment: Why is that ill-advised? Storyboards *can* assist in UI development, but in the end they *cannot* do anything you can't through code. It's like learning command-line versus GUI (be it Assembler v. COBOL or .Net framework v. VS). I'm thinking you are saying something I'm not getting or seeing. In the OP's code, I agree - code against provided overrides properly, using templates with image views (and probably an array of them populated properly).

Comment: @dfd, Assembler vs. Swift is a better analogy. It's true that you can do everything with Assembler that you can do in Swift, but I would not hire a developer who insisted on creating iOS applications in assembler. Likewise I would not hire an iOS dev who refused to use Storyboards and insisted on creating their UIs in code. It's more work up-front, harder to follow, and harder to maintain.

Comment: (And I write this as somebody who has developed commercial software in assembler. That was in the early 1980s, when you had to use assembler in order to get the required performance. Those days are long over, and I haven't written much assembler in at least 20 years. High-level languages are BETTER. Storyboards are BETTER.)

Comment: I've seen one/two failings of Storyboards. (1) If you absolutely *need* a landscape layout different from a portrait on an iPad, you cannot do it all in IB, as iPads have the same size class. (2) Autolayout constraints. While *not* the worst thing, understanding constraints from a coding standpoint greatly helps when creating them in Storyboards. I agree, it's come a long way since Xcode 4 (unified IDE, Storyboards instead of forcing you to create nib, etc.) but I'd hire the developer who understood custom classes and how they relate to a Storyboard over one who can't do it in code.

Comment: Sure, understanding *how* to do it in code is valuable. That's different than *insisting* on doing it in code. There are times when you need to set things up in code vs. Storyboards, but those are rare.

Comment: @DuncanC I agree with you that one should learn/use the tools available, especially when they are being updated regularly, but I do have a use case for adding images in code, because I don't think it's possible in Storyboard. App: create an event, people sign up. I want to display the profile pictures for each person who signed up, like FB. So, I need to dynamically generate UIImage and place them.